# How to normalize the following database of faculty locator?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I take input the department,professor name,day of the week,and time slot during the day.

I return the location of the faculty during that time slot.

Following are the tables i could think of.

```
INSTRUCTOR (inst_id, inst_name, dept)
LOCATION (inst_id, day, time_slot, inst_location, status(available for doubts/teaching))
```

Can i divide the database into more tables?

Comment: 1. One cannot normalize unless one knows all functional dependencies and join dependencies. 2. It is never necessary to add ids to given input attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your functional dependencies are (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
inst_id -> inst_name, dept
(inst_id, day, time_slot) -> inst_location, status
```

These are in order.  In order to answer the question for a given department, professor name, day and time slot, you also need:

```
(inst_name, dept) -> inst_id
```

That is, each instructor must be uniquely identified by name within their department.

Your tables are normalized (not fully but well enough) and you don't need to divide them into more.  Just be sure to include that unique constraint in the INSTRUCTOR table.

Comment: 1. If these FDs and those in their closure are the only ones then these tables are in 5NF. 2. All the candidate keys should be declared. Given the FDs in 1: INSTRUCTOR (inst_id) and (inst_name,dept) and LOCATION (inst_id, day, time_slot). 3. It is never necessary to add ids to given input attributes (as the OP does).